# BCC tool execute failed on Android by debianfs

Tags: ebpf, bpf, bcc, bcc-bpf

While running execsnoop or hello_word example on Android by defbianfs, an error occured.

root@localhost:/# bcc/bcc/examples/hello_world.py
chdir(/tmp//kheaders-6.1.25-android14-11-maybe-dirty): No such file or directory
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "//bcc/bcc/examples/hello_world.py", line 12, in
BPF(text='int kprobe__sys_clone(void *ctx) { bpf_trace_printk("Hello, World!\n"); return 0; }').trace_print()
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/bcc-0.29.1+008ea09e-py3.11.egg/bcc/init.py", line 479, in init
Exception: Failed to compile BPF module

I can't find /tmp//kheaders-6.1.25-android14-11-maybe-dirty.
Where can I find it?